# Convert Regular Expression to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I have a following regular expression:

```
 ^((\d{4}TS\d{0,4}[A-Z0-9]))$
```

I need to convert this in to SQL statement such as

```
  SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM WHERE LIKE Mask ORDER BY field2
```

Comment: Regular expressions have lots of features that `LIKE` patterns don't, and it looks like you're using some of them.

Comment: If you are using mssql you can check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

Comment: Please replace your `sql` tag with the tag for the specific DBMS you're using.

Comment: Why do you have two sets of parentheses around your regexp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using MS Access syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1
FROM Table1
WHERE field1 LIKE '####TS[A-Z0-9]'
OR field1 LIKE '####TS#[A-Z0-9]'
OR field1 LIKE '####TS##[A-Z0-9]'
OR field1 LIKE '####TS###[A-Z0-9]'
OR field1 LIKE '####TS####[A-Z0-9]'
ORDER BY field2
```

Using SQL Server syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1
FROM Table1
WHERE field1 LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]TS[A-Z0-9]'
OR field1 LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]TS[0-9][A-Z0-9]'
OR field1 LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]TS[0-9][0-9][A-Z0-9]'
OR field1 LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]TS[0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z0-9]'
OR field1 LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]TS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z0-9]'
ORDER BY field2
```

Using Oracle syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1
FROM Table1
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(field1, '^[0-9]{4}TS[0-9]{0,4}[A-Z0-9]$')
ORDER BY field2
```

Using MySQL syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1
FROM Table1
WHERE field1 REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}TS[0-9]{0,4}[A-Z0-9]$'
ORDER BY field2
```

Comment: +1 for multiple platforms.  There are [regex functions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server-2005-2008) for MS Sql that work quite well BTW.